# OKD installation behind proxy

Tags: installation, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, okd

Hi everyone  i don't know if i'm the only one have issues installing okd behind proxy in my case i got ovirt for deploy the cluster the openshift-installer is creating the resources all looks fine but when the bootstrap try to get the images is just go in the limbo because to get access i need to put the CA certificate and update-ca-trust to allow internet also i need to export the http and https proxy setting but i can't find any info in the documentaion with similar kind of installation really appreciate any help  if someone has been in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

It is documented in the [Installing a cluster on bare metal in a restricted network](https://docs.okd.io/latest/installing/installing_bare_metal/installing-restricted-networks-bare-metal.html#installation-configure-proxy_installing-restricted-networks-bare-metal) section. So you'll need to edit your `install-config.yaml` file and add the proxy settings:

```
apiVersion: v1
baseDomain: my.domain.com
proxy:
  httpProxy: http://<username>:<pswd>@<ip>:<port> 
  httpsProxy: http://<username>:<pswd>@<ip>:<port> 
  noProxy: example.com 
additionalTrustBundle: | 
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    <MY_TRUSTED_CA_CERT>
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
...
```

Save the file and reference it when installing OKD.